# Create State Service Application and the Usage and Health Data Collection application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Based on this message

"I am going to run some PowerShell scripts to create the State Service Application and the Usage and Health Data Collection application. These came from a presentation that Todd Klindt made at the SharePoint Technical Conference in San Francisco." from the link (http://consultingblogs.emc.com/randyrempel/archive/2013/03/17/installing-and-configuring-sharepoint-2013-part-4-of-4.aspx)

My questions are:

1. How important is it to create the State Service Application and the Usage and Health Data Collection application?
2. How common is it for company to install tate Service Application and the Usage and Health Data Collection application?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would say that it is very important to create both service applications.
2. It is very common to use both service applications in any SharePoint 2013 environment.

Here is some further documentation regarding the [State Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704548.aspx) and the [Usage and Health Data Collection Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663480.aspx).

Plus, here's a short blog post about [core service applications in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.tahoepartners.com/index.php/sharepoint-2013-core-service-applications/).

Comment: If it still important to have number 1 and 2 if you work with workflow and SharePoint development towards app, COM and SOM?

Comment: Yes, the state service is important for workflow while usage & health is vital for logging. I maintain that these functions are important in any production SharePoint environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
In my case, the purpose is to learn my knowledge in Workflow and sharepoint developent towards app, COM and SOM. I'm not gonna use it for production environment. Just to my educuational purpose with development phase only. Do I still need to have number 1 and 2 in my context?

Comment: Both service applications are easy enough to enable. You can go without, but I'm not sure why you would. Even if your environment is not for prod, you may want to dig into logs and allow workflow to access user state etc. Of course, you are free to do as you please! Just my 2 cents.